# Where, in Exchange, can rules from other sources be removed?

Tags: email, exchange

I have one user, out of almost 500, who has connected his Android phone to Microsoft Exchange; I've ensured that this has been done correctly, but he, at one time, set up some inbox rules from the phone.  After a few days all of his internal mail is being moved to a **Junk** folder after hitting the inbox.  To clarify: it is not *the* junk folder, but *a* folder within the inbox that is labeled **Junk**.

Any thoughts or advice would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: The rules are either server-side, or client-side. So exist either on the Exchange server, or on the phone. Are the messages getting moved BEFORE he checks in (as soon as they hit the server)? Have you checked the Exchange server for server-side rules being applied to his account?  Which Mail application is he using on the phone?  Have you checked it for rules that may be applied?

Comment: @techie007 the answer is email client related so is not an serverfault question. I believe whomever migrated this question to ServerFault did so in error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this a Samsung device by chance? It would seem their client does some "spam handling" and has it's own managed sender list.  I know Samsung's mail client is not the stock Android one.

```
Select Settings

Select General Settings

Select Spam addresses
```

Delete any inappropriate entries. Actually, I recommend you delete ANY entries, and let Exchange do your spam work, or a full Outlook client manage safe sender / blocked sender lists.

[Reference](http://msexchange.me/2014/01/25/exchange-active-sync-user-mails-going-to-junk-folder/)

You can check (double check) Exchange mailbox config by running the following PowerShell command:

`Get-InboxRule -Mailbox <username>`

Comment: As a matter of fact it is a Samsung Galaxy SIII.  The shell command yielded no inbox rules currently active.

Thank you though, I appreciate the insight.

Comment: Definitely check the steps in my reference link then. Check application settings in Samsung's mail client.   The good news is: no server side rules!

Comment: Your reference link was exactly the same issue and did fix it.  Our company's domain was listed right there in **Spam Addresses**.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

With the right mailbox permissions you could possibly run Outlook with a profile set to that users account.

If you are able to get those permissions then you can start Outlook with the `/cleanrules` switch, which will reset all the server rules, and any rules in that profile.  Here is a helpful list of all the [Outlook switches](http://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/commandlineswitches.htm).

Comment: The list of Outlook switches is very helpful; I shall be using that in the future!
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The issue lies with the Android phone and is a localized issue. It is up to the user (or by your grace, your tech support) to fix on the Android phone, not on Exchange.

Comment: I was afraid of that.  Not even my usual "remove and re-add" worked this time.